# Read duplicate datarows from database into business objects and distinct them using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates, reshape

This is the data in my database table:

[image]

That's my business object:

```
public class Unit
    {
        public Unit()
        {
            MemberIdList = new List<String>();
        }

        public String UnitType { get; set; }
        public String UnitZoom { get; set; }
        public String MemberZoom { get; set; }

        public List<String> MemberIdList { get; set; }
    }
```

The whole data from database is fetched and put into a DataTable.

**Now comes the Linq Transformation...**

After I return a List with 3 Unit objects holding this data:

[image]

Now guess how I got the data into the 3 business objects... 
that's the way I would like to know. A hint might be Distinct and IEqualityComparer for the 3 properties...
just an assumption...

**UPDATE**

Question updated:

Please read the comment in the code :)

```
var groupedCollection = table.AsEnumerable()
                                    .GroupBy(row => new
                                    {
                                        UType = row.Field<string>("UnitType"),
                                        UZoom = row.Field<string>("UnitZoom"),
                                        MZoom = row.Field<string>("MemberZoom"),
                                        MOrder = row.Field<int>("MemberOrder"),
```

// I DO NOT WANT the MemberOrder to be in the Group Key, but later on I use this Property to order by it... 
                                        });

```
            var unitCollection = groupedCollection
                                .Select(g => new Unit 
                                {
                                    UnitType = g.Key.UType,
                                    UnitZoom = g.Key.UZoom,
                                    MemberZoom = g.Key.MZoom,                                   
                                    MemberIdList = g.Select(r => r.Field<string>("MemberId")).OrderBy(b => g.Key.MOrder).ToList(),
                                });

            List<Unit> units = unitCollection.ToList();
```

Comment: You should split your table into two to avoid the same rows. Than you can use Linq2Sql directly agains it and get the same structure as in your business object

Comment: cant change anything here. It is as it is ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
DataTable dt = ...

var list = 
dt.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(r => new
{
    UType = r.Field<string>("UnitType"),
    UZoom = r.Field<string>("UnitZoom"),
    MZoom = r.Field<string>("MemberZoom")
})
.Select(g => new Unit 
{ 
    UnitType = g.Key.UType, 
    UnitZoom = g.Key.UZoom, 
    MemberZoom = g.Key.MZoom ,
    MemberIdList = g.Select(r => r.Field<string>("MemberId")).Distinct().ToList()
})
.ToList();
```

**EDIT:**
the call to `.Distinct()` is not strictly necessary. It avoids duplicated MemberIds if you can have them, but it really depends on what OP needs.

**EDIT2:**
(according to the last question update)

You are close to the solution:

just change this line of my code:

```
MemberIdList = g.Select(r => r.Field<string>("MemberId")).ToList()
```

to:

```
MemberIdList = g.Select(r => r.Field<string>("MemberId")).OrderBy(r => r.Field<int>("MOrder")).ToList()
```

Comment: @digEmAll Dont think the `Distinct()` is needed

Comment: btw.why do you Distinct the MemberId? the grouping is ok to understand, but I would have rather distincted the 3 properties... but it works lol ;-)

Comment: @Magnus YES therefore I wrote thats ok to understand... I just got confused about the distinct and you were right it works without distinct. I just have a problem understand how the MemberIdList is filled... Must again study .Select(...

Comment: @Magnus: sorry for the late reply but my connection died... yes, Distinct is not strictlty necessary, but I added it just in case he want to remove duplicated memberids if any... My intention was to add a note about that, but I couldn't connect until now...

Comment: @digEmAll sorry for the late reply but I forgot sorthing ;P Just think I still have a 5th column in my table called MemberOrder which is of type integer.For example Both Unit Type A has a MemberOrder 0 and 1. That means the way/order the MemberId is written/added to the MemberIdList is determined by the MemberOrder number. How can I extend the existing code so that every MemberId is added in a certain Order into the MemberIdList ? I have updated my question with a piece of code why it does not work. Would be nice if you could assist me thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
var values = TblMembers.ToList();

var lst = 
    (from m in values
    group m by new { m.UnitType, m.UnitZoom, m.MemberZoom } into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.UnitType,
        g.Key.UnitZoom,
        g.Key.MemberZoom,
        MemberIdList = g.Select (x => x.MemberID).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result =
        from n in data
        group n by new { n.UnitType, n.UnitZoom, n.MemberZoom } into g
        select new Unit 
        { 
          UnitType = g.Key.UnitType, 
          UnitZoom = g.Key.UnitZoom, 
          MemberZoom = g.Key.MemberZoom , 
          MemberIdList = g.Select ( r => r.MemberId).ToList() 
        };
```